# Materialize Select Drop down issue in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, html-select, materialize

I am working on a project using Materialize in WordPress.

It's all working fine, but we have run into a problem when trying to implement in Google Chrome.

Here is my code

```
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option>Value 1</option>
            <option>Value 2</option>
            <option>Value 3</option>
            <option>Value 4</option>
            <option>Value 5</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

And here is jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('select').material_select();
    });
</script>
```

When i run my project in Google Chrome, in console i face this issue

[image]

[image]
It would be great if anyone has info on this.

Thanks!

Comment: find replace statements in material_select() function.This error occurs when you replace text of element that is not defined

Comment: Option value is not given as attribute

Comment: Nowadays, lots of problem coming in google chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `options` a `value` attribute.

Try:

```
   <select>
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
        <option value="4">Value 4</option>
        <option value="5">Value 5</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: i trying with value but same result

Comment: I think jQuery cannot find the element.

Comment: Thanks Bas Van Stein your suggestion was correct and now my issue have been solved

Answer (score 0):

You are using different identifiers for jquery (jQuery & $) in your code.
I checked this works fine on firefox but gives errors on chrome,
try changing it to

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('select').material_select();
    });
```

Not sure if solves the problem , but correct way using it is as above.

Comment: Dear nshah143 i use this in WordPress and in WordPress if i use ($) in my code then WordPress shows error ($) is not define

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue.. It was working and then stopped. Here is how I solved it on my end:

```
<select class="browser-default">
    <option>OPTION 1</option>
    <option>OPTION 2</option>
</select>
```